# Javascript editor for EaselJS code complete

Tags: javascript, ide, code-completion, easeljs

What javascript editor I can use for EaselJS code complete? 
I tried Aptana plugin for eclipse but it did not work out, I also tried making an uncompressed file using below command and import the uncompress file

> node ./build.js --format=PRETTY_PRINT

I also tried to look for sdocml for EaselJS but I could not find any.

Does any one know how we can get  EaselJS code complete?

Thanks

-Maaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though this is nothing official and unfortunately I haven't had the time to adjust this to EaselJS 0.6.0 here is a code-completion for SublimeText: http://indiegamr.com/easeljs-codecompletion-for-sublimetext2/ - but be aware, this is no 'intelligent' completion as you might be used to from Java or AS3, but it includes the methods and attributes ect. from 0.5.0

There is also a TypeScript-definition for CreateJS: https://bitbucket.org/drk4/createjs_ts_definitions (unfortunately also only EaselJS 0.5.0) - but TypeScript is a way better choice than pure JS if you want a good/intelligent code-completion. - But maybe you can find something for 0.6.0 for this on the web.

*Edit: This looks like an updated version for TypeScript: https://nuget.org/packages/easeljs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/